# How to calculate the night working shift in SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, fingerprint, time-and-attendance

I'm using Fingerprint system to record the IN OUT log of all employee in 4 shifts .Normal shift(08:00-> 17:00) , Shift 1:(06-> 14:00), Shift 2: (14:00-> 22:00) Shift 3:(22:00-> 06:00 tomorrow) . I have 2 main table :
[image]

[image]

When I use the left join :

```
select e.Id as EmpID,CAST(PunchTime as DATE)CheckDate,MIN(cast(a.PunchTime as Time))[TimeIN], max(cast(a.PunchTime as Time))[Time_OUT]
from Employee e
left join AttLog a
on a.EnrollNumber=e.EnrollNumber 
group by e.Id,CAST(PunchTime as DATE)
```

[image]

and when I use the inner join :

```
select e.Id as EmpID,CAST(PunchTime as DATE)CheckDate,MIN(cast(a.PunchTime as Time))[TimeIN], max(cast(a.PunchTime as Time))[Time_OUT]
from Employee e
inner join AttLog a
on a.EnrollNumber=e.EnrollNumber 
group by e.Id,CAST(PunchTime as DATE)
```

[image]

Then , you see when using left join we get all the employee including null time.
And when we use inner join we just get the Time IN = Time OUT if the employee working in the Shift 3 (22:00 today to 06:00 tomorrow) .
So my question is how to calculate the time IN and OUT of Shift 3.
And if the employee punch only IN then Time OUT = Time IN , how can display time OUT as 00:00:00 in that case.
I want to output like this:

```
EmpID  CheckDate   TimeIN                       Time_OUT
5      2015-08-19    2015-08-19 07:51:29.000      2015-08-20 07:43:57.000
14     2015-08-19    2015-08-19 06:52:26.000      2015-08-19 00:00:00.000
```

EmpID 5 with normal working: 08:00->17:00 but he must took night duty so he must stay at the company until 08:00 tomorrow.
EmpID 14 work in normal shift but she forgot to punch OUT.
At the present with above data , the output like this:

```
EmpID  CheckDate   TimeIN                       Time_OUT
    5      2015-08-19    2015-08-19 07:51:29.000      2015-08-19 07:51:29.000
    5      2015-08-20    2015-08-20 07:43:57.000      2015-08-20 07:43:57.000
    14     2015-08-19    2015-08-19 06:52:26.000       2015-08-19 06:52:26.000
```

Comment: My problem is the same with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15797239/attendance-for-night-shift-in-time-and-out-time-not-coming-properly-in-sql-serve?rq=1 but no satisfied answer for this. Is it very difficult?

Comment: Please edit your question to include ddl + dml for sample data and desired output.

Comment: What is the InOutMode column? Does it help us determine if a value in the  PunchTime column was a Punch In or  Punch Out?

Comment: This fingerprint system data log  does not have InOutMode , only have PunchTime column that contain the datetime . So to count IN or OUT we use Min and Max time . I tried to google a lot but not yet received any satisfied answer for this case. It is imposible?

Comment: It's possible, but you won't be able to use MIN and MAX, as you've already found out. I will give you a basic solution but you will have to modify it with logic to account for people missing punches, etc.

Comment: @PeterDNCO SO, how to do? Please help ! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach that sequences the punch times, and then self-joins with a recursive CTE to stitch times together. It's hard with a system like this to control for missed punches etc., but I tried show you a way you could do it by adding in an HoursWorked threshold.

```
/* Create some sample Employee punch data to test*/
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#AttLogTest') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #AttLogTest

CREATE TABLE #AttLogTest (EnrollNumber INT NOT NULL, PunchTime DATETIME NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO #AttLogTest (EnrollNumber, PunchTime)
SELECT 10, '2015-08-01 08:01:03' UNION ALL
SELECT 10, '2015-08-02 07:57:35' UNION ALL
SELECT 10, '2015-08-01 16:15:23' UNION ALL
SELECT 10, '2015-08-02 16:17:46' UNION ALL
SELECT 12, '2015-08-01 21:59:31' UNION ALL
SELECT 12, '2015-08-02 05:59:02' UNION ALL
SELECT 12, '2015-08-02 22:02:28' UNION ALL
SELECT 12, '2015-08-03 06:01:24' UNION ALL
SELECT 14, '2015-08-01 07:59:01' UNION ALL
SELECT 14, '2015-08-02 07:58:16' UNION ALL
SELECT 14, '2015-08-02 16:02:48'

/* Employee time query logic below */

/* First, create a temp table that sequences the punch times for each employee */
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#EmployeeTimeSequence') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #EmployeeTimeSequence

SELECT
    EnrollNumber
    ,PunchTime
    ,PunchSequence = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EnrollNumber ORDER BY PunchTime)
INTO #EmployeeTimeSequence
FROM #AttLogTest --Replace this with your dbo.AttLog table if this solution works for you
/*WHERE clause could be added here to filter for specific dates or EnrollNumbers */


/* If time between punches is greater than this threashold, then it will be treated as a missed punch
  in logic below. Remove this or modify as needed. */
DECLARE @MissedPunchThreshold int
SET @MissedPunchThreshold = 20

/* Next, create a recursive CTE which will stitch together the punch times and ensure punch times don't overlap when 
 self-joining to #EmployeeTimeSequence. */
;WITH EmployeeTimeCTE (EnrollNumber, CheckDate, Time_In, Time_Out, HoursBetweenPunch, PunchOutSequence)
AS (
    /* Anchor member */
    SELECT 
        ETS_In.EnrollNumber
        ,CAST(ETS_In.PunchTime AS DATE) AS CheckDate
        ,ETS_In.PunchTime AS Time_In
        ,ETS_Out.PunchTime AS Time_Out
        ,DateDiff(hour, ETS_In.PunchTime, ETS_Out.PunchTime) AS HoursBetweenPunch
        ,ETS_Out.PunchSequence AS PunchOutSequence
    FROM #EmployeeTimeSequence AS ETS_In
    LEFT OUTER JOIN #EmployeeTimeSequence AS ETS_Out
        ON ETS_In.EnrollNumber = ETS_Out.EnrollNumber
        AND ETS_Out.PunchSequence = ETS_In.PunchSequence + 1
    WHERE ETS_In.PunchSequence = 1

    UNION ALL
    /* Recursive memebr - build on top of anchor */
        SELECT 
            ETS_In.EnrollNumber
            ,CAST(ETS_In.PunchTime AS DATE) AS CheckDate
            ,ETS_In.PunchTime AS Time_In
            ,ETS_Out.PunchTime AS Time_Out
            ,DateDiff(hour, ETS_In.PunchTime, ETS_Out.PunchTime) AS HoursBetweenPunch
            ,ETS_Out.PunchSequence AS PunchOutSequence
    FROM #EmployeeTimeSequence AS ETS_In --get the time for the in punch
    INNER JOIN EmployeeTimeCTE ET
        ON ET.EnrollNumber = ETS_In.EnrollNumber
            AND ETS_In.PunchSequence =
                CASE
                    WHEN ET.HoursBetweenPunch > @MissedPunchThreshold -- if more than threshold, then treat as missed punch
                        THEN ET.PunchOutSequence -- then treat the previous out punch as the next in punch instead
                    ELSE ET.PunchOutSequence + 1  -- else join as usual to get the next punch in sequence
                END 
    INNER JOIN #EmployeeTimeSequence AS ETS_Out -- get the time for the out punch
        ON ETS_In.EnrollNumber = ETS_Out.EnrollNumber
        AND ETS_Out.PunchSequence = ETS_In.PunchSequence + 1
)
/* Now query the CTE */
SELECT 
    EnrollNumber AS EmpID
    ,CheckDate 
    ,Time_In
    ,CASE WHEN HoursBetweenPunch > @MissedPunchThreshold THEN NULL ELSE Time_Out END AS Time_Out
    ,CASE WHEN HoursBetweenPunch > @MissedPunchThreshold THEN NULL ELSE HoursBetweenPunch END AS HoursBetweenPunch
FROM EmployeeTimeCTE
ORDER BY EnrollNumber, CheckDate
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 1000)
```

Comment: Thank you very much , I test your code it works, Imust apply this code to my project . Hope it works!

Comment: Cool, hope it works for your project. You may have to add some extra logic to handle some of the edge cases like the Emp5 in your example who works a normal shift but then pulls night duty and is there for a total of 24 hours. Could get interesting - good luck :)

Answer (score 2):

You can refer the below solution which I have got after lot of research. This Solution works only in SQL 2012 or above.

```
;WITH Level1 
AS ( SELECT 
     EmpName (or EmpID) 
    ,TrnName (Exit or Entrance)
    ,EntryDateTime
    ,LAG (TrnName, 1, 'N/A') OVER ( PARTITION BY EmpName ORDER BY EntryDateTime) AS LastEvent
    ,LEAD(TrnName, 1, 'N/A') OVER ( PARTITION BY EmpName ORDER BY EventDateTime ) AS NextEvent 
    FROM #TempData 

    ),
Level2
AS ( SELECT 
     EmpName 
    ,TrnName 
    ,EntryDateTime 
    ,LastEvent
    ,NextEvent 
    FROM   Level1 
    WHERE
        NOT ( TrnName = 'Entrance' AND NextEvent = 'Entrance' )
        AND NOT ( TrnName = 'Entrance' AND LastEvent = 'Entrance' )
        AND NOT ( TrnName = 'Exit' AND LastEvent = 'Exit' )
        AND NOT ( TrnName = 'Entrance' AND NextEvent = 'N/A' ) 
        AND NOT (TrnName = 'Exit' AND LastEvent = 'N/A' )
    ),
Level3
AS ( SELECT 
     EmpName
    ,TrnName 
    ,EntryDateTime 
    ,DATEDIFF(second, EntryDateTime,LEAD(EntryDateTime) OVER ( PARTITION BY EmpName ORDER BY EntryDateTime )) AS Seconds 
    FROM Level2 
    )

SELECT 
     EmpName 
    ,EntryDateTime 
    ,(EntryDateTime+convert(DateTime,TIMEFROMPARTS((Seconds%(3600*24)/3600), ((Seconds%(3600*24)%3600)/60), ((Seconds%(3600*24)%3600)%60),0, 0))) AS ExitDateTime
    ,Seconds
    ,TIMEFROMPARTS((Seconds%(3600*24)/3600), ((Seconds%(3600*24)%3600)/60), ((Seconds%(3600*24)%3600)%60),0, 0) AS WorkTime
    FROM Level3 
    WHERE 
        TrnName = 'Entrance'
```

This can be helpful and can be improved by adding threshold code provided by  **PeterDNCO**.